# Libgit2sharp - equivalent to "git describe --tag"

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

So I am working on a system to determine the changes since the last tag.
Git offers the `git describe --tag` command which will:

> The command finds the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe

However, I am using Libgit2sharp to do some automation and I am looking for the equivalent functionality however I am not having much luck.

I tried:

```cs
var result = repo.Refs.ReachableFrom(
  repo.Refs.Where(r => r.IsTag),
  new[] { repo.Head.Tip });
```

But this didn't yield any results (I am pretty use I am doing it wrong)

Answer (score 0):

This is my current naive approach. I am open to criticism or better solutions.
The commit log is ordered and therefore I just find the nearest tag targeting a commit and use that.

In my case I always using HEAD as I am looking for the last tag at the tip of HEAD.

```cs
Tag? GetLastTag(Repository repo)
{
    var commitsToHead = repo.Head.Commits;
    var tagsOnCommits = repo.Tags.Where(t => t.Target.GetType() == typeof(Commit)).ToList();

    foreach (var commit in commitsToHead)
    {
        var foundTags = tagsOnCommits.Where(x => x.Target.Peel<Commit>().Id == commit.Id).ToArray();
        if (foundTags.Length <= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (foundTags.Length > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Found more than one tag for the commit {commit}");
        }

        return foundTags[0];
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Just a note I am getting issues with this running on Github actions on a PR merge